# Convergence of Sequence Implies Convergence of Norms

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am trying to find the limit of a sequence if $(x_n)$ is a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $\lim_{n \to \infty} (x_n)= a$, show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} ||x_n|| = ||a||,$ where these are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. And I am also trying to show that the converse of this is false by an example

Comment: If $x_n\to a$, each coordinate of $x_n$ tends to each coordinate of $a$, hence the square do, hence the sum does, hence the square root of the sum does, which is the norm. Alternatively, $$|\lVert x\rVert -\lVert y\rVert |\leqslant \lVert x-y\rVert$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Use $\vert\Vert x_n\Vert-\Vert a\Vert\vert\leq\Vert x_n-a\Vert$.

If you do not have this inequality, fiddle with the triangle inequality until you get this.

Edit: The inequality $\vert\Vert x\Vert-\Vert y\Vert\vert\leq\Vert x-y\Vert$ implies that the norm is continuous. As a consequence, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\Vert x_n\Vert=\Vert\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n\Vert=\Vert a\Vert$.

Comment: So if I get that, then that implies that the lim(xn)=a and lim||xn||= ||a|| I just don't see how I can use that to prove the limits

Comment: @jbebe44 $\lim ||x_n|| - ||a|| \leq \lim | \, ||x_n|| - ||a|| \,| \leq \lim ||x_n - a|| = 0$

Comment: Let $\delta=\epsilon$ in the definition of continuity.

Comment: then how would I find show that the converse is false?

Comment: That's not part of your original question, but let $e_i$ be the standard basis vectors for $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $x_m=e_1$ for all $m$ and $a=-e_1$. Then $\lim x_m=\lim e_1=e_1\neq -e_1=a$ but $\lim\Vert x_m\Vert =1=\Vert a\Vert$.